# Python regex - get items from orgmode files

Tags: python, regex, org-mode

I have the following org-mode syntax:

```
** Hardware [0/1]
 - [ ] adapt a programmable motor to a tripod to be used for panning 
** Reading - Technology [1/6]
 - [X] Introduction to Networking - Charles Severance
 - [ ] A Tour of C++ - Bjarne Stroustrup
 - [ ] C++ How to Program - Paul Deitel
 - [X] Computer Systems - Randal Bryant
 - [ ] The C programming language - Brian Kernighan
 - [ ] Beginning Linux Programming -Matthew and Stones
** Reading - Health [3/4]
 - [ ] Patrick McKeown - The Oxygen Advantage
 - [X] Total Knee Health - Martin Koban
 - [X] Supple Leopard - Kelly Starrett
 - [X] Convict Conditioning 1 and 2
```

and I want to extract the items, such as:

```
 getitems "Hardware"
```

I should get:

```
  - [ ] adapt a programmable motor to a tripod to be used for panning
```

if I ask for  "Reading - Health", I should get:

```
 - [ ] Patrick McKeown - The Oxygen Advantage
 - [X] Total Knee Health - Martin Koban
 - [X] Supple Leopard - Kelly Starrett
 - [X] Convict Conditioning 1 and 2
```

I am using the following pattern:

```
   pattern = re.compile("\*\* "+ head + " (.+?)\*?$", re.DOTALL)
```

the output when asking for "Reading - Technology" is:

```
  - [X] Introduction to Networking - Charles Severance
  - [ ] A Tour of C++ - Bjarne Stroustrup
  - [ ] C++ How to Program - Paul Deitel
  - [X] Computer Systems - Randal Bryant
  - [ ] The C programming language - Brian Kernighan
  - [ ] Beginning Linux Programming -Matthew and Stones
   ** Reading - Health [3/4]
  - [ ] Patrick McKeown - The Oxygen Advantage
  - [X] Total Knee Health - Martin Koban
  - [X] Supple Leopard - Kelly Starrett
  - [X] Convict Conditioning 1 and 2
```

I also tried:

```
   pattern = re.compile("\*\* "+ head + " (.+?)[\*|\z]", re.DOTALL)
```

this last one works fine for all the headers except for the last one.

output when asking for "Reading - Health":

```
 - [ ] Patrick McKeown - The Oxygen Advantage
 - [X] Total Knee Health - Martin Koban
 - [X] Supple Leopard - Kelly Starrett
```

As you can see, it doesn't match the last line.

I'm using python 2.7, and findall.

Comment: `\*\* Reading - Health (.*?)(?:\*\*|$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it with

```
import re

string = """
** Hardware [0/1]
 - [ ] adapt a programmable motor to a tripod to be used for panning 
** Reading - Technology [1/6]
 - [X] Introduction to Networking - Charles Severance
 - [ ] A Tour of C++ - Bjarne Stroustrup
 - [ ] C++ How to Program - Paul Deitel
 - [X] Computer Systems - Randal Bryant
 - [ ] The C programming language - Brian Kernighan
 - [ ] Beginning Linux Programming -Matthew and Stones
** Reading - Health [3/4]
 - [ ] Patrick McKeown - The Oxygen Advantage
 - [X] Total Knee Health - Martin Koban
 - [X] Supple Leopard - Kelly Starrett
 - [X] Convict Conditioning 1 and 2  
 """

def getitems(section):
    rx = re.compile(r'^\*{2} ' + re.escape(section) + r'.+[\n\r](?P<block>(?:(?!^\*{2})[\s\S])+)', re.MULTILINE)
    try:
        items = rx.search(string)
        return items.group('block')
    except:
        return None

items = getitems('Reading - Technology')
print(items)
```

See it [**working on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/57dzQK).

---

The heart of the code is the (condensed) expression:

```
^\*{2}.+[\n\r]       # match the beginning of the line, followed by two stars, anything else in between and a newline
(?P<block>           # open group "block"
    (?:              # non-capturing group
        (?!^\*{2})   # a neg. lookahead, making sure no ** follows at the beginning of a line
        [\s\S]       # any character...
    )+               # ...at least once
)                    # close group "block"
```

where your search string is inserted after `**` in the actual code. See a demo for `Reading - Technology` on **[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CHt4Wl/1)**.

---

As a follow-up, you could as well only return the **selected values**, like so:

```
def getitems(section, selected=None):
    rx = re.compile(r'^\*{2} ' + re.escape(section) + r'.+[\n\r](?P<block>(?:(?!^\*{2})[\s\S])+)', re.MULTILINE)
    try:
        items = rx.search(string).group('block')
        if selected:
            rxi = re.compile(r'^ - \[X\]\ (.+)', re.MULTILINE)
            try:
                selected_items = rxi.findall(items)
                return selected_items
            except:
                return None
         return items
    except:
        return None

items = getitems('Reading - Health', selected=True)
print(items)
```

Comment: thanks, it improved the overall code.. and also regex101.com is an awesome website

Comment: @daleonpz: Added a version to return only the selected values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that the character `*` is not present in your items, you can use:

```
re.compile(r"\*\* "+head+r" \[\d+/\d+\]\n([^*]+)\*?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not certain you need a regex for the entire match. I'd just use a regex to match the `**` line, and then return lines until you see the next `**` line.

Something like

```
pattern = re.compile("\*\* "+ head)

start = False
output = []
for line in my_file:
    if pattern.match(line):
         start = True
         continue
    elif line.startswith("**"): # but doesn't match pattern
        break

    if start:
        output.append(line)

# now `output` should have the lines you want
```

Comment: regex is great at matching structured data, like a line that always has a specific format. It becomes a lot trickier to use when you have to match a bunch of random text between the lines that you care about, which is why i generally avoid the method you were trying to do.

Comment: on second glance, the `pattern.match` in my answer might also just as well be a `line.startswith("** " + head)`